# How to read and set DevOps Pipeline variables using Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have an Azure Pipeline setup with MyVariable variable defined:

[image: MyVariable]

How do I write Azure PowerShell Inline Script to read the variable, and set it to a value after some processing?

[image: You can write your azure powershell scripts inline here.]

Answer (score 9):

**Reading**:

Variables are exposed as environment-variables, to read the variable "TestVar" you can do this:

```
$myScriptVariable = $env:TESTVAR
```

Note that "." will be replaced with "_" and all is uppercase.

**Setting or Updating:**

To set or update a variable you'll have to write following 'command' to the host with "write-host":

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

There are more logging-commands for different actions, i'll just leave the link to the documentation here -> https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: Be advised that uppercase is important. I went down a rabbit hole of trying to get this to work while using lowercase characters and my pipeline kept failing. It was because you must do all caps and replace periods with underscores as this answer  suggests.

Answer (score 1):

build variables are exposed as environment variables inside build steps, so you can just reference it using normal powershell syntax:

```
$env:MyVariable
```

Comment: You are only answering half of the question