# How to access environment variables in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have created a variable in pipeline as follows,

[image]

But I cannot modify or read its value inside pipeline steps. I tried several formats but it doesn't fetch the value. What is the correct format of accessing its value?

```
Write-Host " bla bla: $($Env:versionnumber)"
Write-Host " bla bla: $($env:versionnumber)"
Write-Host " bla bla: $versionnumber"
Write-Host " bla bla: $($versionnumber)"
```

Comment: like you normally would in powershell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and set DevOps Pipeline variables using Azure PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129487/how-to-read-and-set-devops-pipeline-variables-using-azure-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Write-Host "bla bla $env:versionnumber"`

Comment: please see my answer, it should be in uppercase `Write-Host "bla bla $env:VERSIONNUMBER"`

Comment: @Channa that's really weird, because I tried it out before writing the answer and it worked without making it uppercased..

Comment: This is not correct. Wrapping variables in `$()` during string interpolation is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Write-Host " bla bla: ($versionnumber)" - Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

It is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) that `Name is upper-cased`, that means we have to use uppercase letters when accessing variables. I used lower case and it doesn't work.

> Notice that variables are also made available to scripts through
>   environment variables. The syntax for using these environment
>   variables depends on the scripting language. Name is upper-cased, .
>   replaced with _, and automatically inserted into the process
>   environment. Here are some examples:
>
> Batch script: %VARIABLE_NAME%  PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
>   Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME

Comment: PowerShell is not case-sensitive. This is trivially tested: `$env:COMPUTERNAME` and `$env:computername` both return the same value.

Comment: No it doesn't, At least in my case. I tried with both ways and it only works with Uppercase.