# Retrieve key vault secret into a variable using azure cli task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I am trying to retrieve a password from key vault secret into a variable in an azure CLI task. But it is not populating any value.
Please find below the YAML task:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Retrieve and store key vault secret
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription'
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      $secret=$(az keyvault secret show --name "passwordSecret" --vault-name "passwordKeyVault")
```

If I use $(secret) anywhere it gives me value as $(secret) only and not the password. Is it the right way to do this? Can someone please guide me through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed. The keyVault was getting deployed at the same time with the common arm template resulting in giving "no current version available" in the secret. Hence, $secret was not able to fetch any value.
I created a separate deployment task for key vault and it worked. Thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not setting the pipeline variable and just setting your script's variable. To **Set/Update variable in ADO pipeline**, you can add below command:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;issecret=true]testvalue"
```

Check out [How to read and set DevOps Pipeline variables using Azure PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129487/how-to-read-and-set-devops-pipeline-variables-using-azure-powershell) and [Use output from AzureCLI@2 as variable in Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933351/use-output-from-azurecli2-as-variable-in-azure-devops-pipeline) for more information.

Comment: Leaving out `isSecret=true` means that the secret will leak in the logs any time it's printed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map it Azure Pipelines variables and for that purpose you should use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)

Since you fetched your value from KeyVault I would recommend you to consider it as secret also in Azure Pipelines. So you need to use this syntax:

```
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;issecret=true]$secret"
```

Where `secretSauce` is a name of the Azure Pipeline variable you will create.

It will cause putting `***` anywhere in logs where normally you secret would appear.

However, secrets are not mapped automatically to env variables and you need to use [env mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) if you need that value accessible via env variables.

Comment: I tried this. I am using a deployment task to deploy few resources like azure sql server and sql db via ARM Template. So in this deployment task I am trying to override the parameter used for sqlAdminPassword like : 

`overrideParameters: >
-sqlAdminPassword $(secretSauce)`

but this is giving me the value as $(secretSauce) only and not the actual value inside the variable secretSauce. Also, all other parameters are getting overriden correctly. Am I doing anything wrong here ?